# “Have some of that to see you home.”

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is an excerpt from [a fiction story](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2022/01/17/fireworks).

> But, before he could make his departure, Bob, with apologies, plonked
> a steaming mug into his hand. **“Have some of that to see you home.”**
>
> See him home? Fifty yards.
>
> He sniffed the steam and recognized the faintly earthy smell. Bob
> couldn’t have known.
>
> “Bovril,” Bob said. “That is, Bovril with a good slug of Scotch in it.
> You wouldn’t think it would make such a good mix.”

I wonder which of the following three the sentence in bold means here.

1. (You) Have some of that and I will see you home.
2. Have some of that and see yourself home.
3. I have some of that in order to see you at my home.

Comment: It means 'the hot drink will keep you warm inside while you walk to your home'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To 'see someone home' is to go with that person all the way to their home, with the intention of protecting them from harm, getting lost, etc. The hot drink (Bovril is a British drink made of beef extract and hot water, and Scotch whisky is also a 'warming' thing) is intended to keep the person feeling warm during their journey home. It will do that by being inside them.

> see verb (GO WITH)
>
> to take someone somewhere by going there with them:
>
> *Her friends saw her home.*

[See (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see)

Answer (score -3):

Closer to your suggestion #2.

His friend is presenting a mug of something to him and tells him to take it with the intention that he will drink it on the way home.  His friend does not say what is in the mug, he calls it "that".  The "to see you home" part means that it is not to be drunk while he is at his friend's house.

Comment: the following sentences "Borvil, with a good slug of Scoth in it" have nothing doing with "That"

Comment: @Blessie - **Bovril**, with **Scotch** added, is a hot drink, and 'that' _does_ refer to it.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that he is to drink it on the way home - just that the drink will give him the strength to walk home, and keep him warm on the way.

Comment: In one of the answers, it says he does not say what’s in the mug and refers it to ‘that’ does the friend know or doesn’t know what’s in the mug? It’s confusing

Comment: @Blessie - In his second speech, Bob tells his friend what is in the mug - but the friend has already recognised the smell.